# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED node.js (express) и express-http-proxy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Доброго времени суток. Возникла проблема, сводящая меня с ума. Уже второй день бьюсь над ней. Есть два файла, app.js и api.js.

// app.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

app.use('/api', proxy('http://localhost:8888'));

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err.message);
});
```

//api.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/bookshop');

var Users = require('./models/users');
```

и далее обращение к маршрутам...

В конце api.js указывается, что данный скрипт прослушивается на 8888 порту:

```
app.listen(8888, err => {
  if (err) console.log(err);

  console.log('worked on http://localhost:8888');
});
```

внутри api.js должно происходить обращение к маршрутам и к бд, но дело до обращения так и не доходит, так как при обращении к сайту мне возвращается следующее:

```
"connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888"
```

Данное сообщение возвращает эта middleware из app.js:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
   console.log(err.message);
});
```

В package.json в "scripts" я указал, что бы запускался и сервер app.js (3000 порт) и сервер api.js (8888 порт), но при обновлении страницы на сайте происходит обращение по адресу localhost:3000/api/users а не localhost:8888/api/users

Помогите одолеть эту напасть! Уже сил никаких нет, весь интернет исполосовал, но решение проблемы так и не нашлось

ЗЫ на рабочем компьютере этот код работает прекрасно, но дома наотрез отказывается. 
На работе x32 windows 8.1, дома x64 windows 8.1, если это важно.

Comment: А что Вам говорит `netstat -a | findstr LISTEN`?

Comment: ссылка на изображение: https://ibb.co/bKyjRk

Comment: Хотел добавить, что если запускать скрипты отдельно, т.е. в одном терминале вызывать node app.js а во втором node api.js, то все работает прекрасно